# Need help improving a tightly coupled design

Tags: java, junit

I have an in-house enterprise application (EJB2) that works with a certain BPM vendor.  The current implementation of the in-house application involves pulling in an object that is only exposed by the vendor's API and making changes to it through the exposed methods in the API.

I'm thinking that I need to somehow map an internal object to this external one, but that seems too simple and I'm not quite sure of the best strategy to go about doing this. Can anyone shed some light on how they have handled such a situation in the past?

I want to "black box" this vendor's software so I can replace it easily if needed.  What would be the best approach from a design point of view to somehow map an internal object to this exposed API object?  Keep in mind that my in-house app needs to talk to the API still, so there is going to be some dependency between the two, but I want to reduce it so I can also test in isolation from this software using junit.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Unless there is some particular constraint in the app, the answers below depict the standard way of abstraction(using interface). I am sure you already knew this so I am curious if there is anything specific in your app that might make this difficult. Also, not trying to piggy back here, but if you wish to make really losely coupled, you can use Spring IOC instead of "new MyAPIEndpoint();"

Comment: I was looking for more confirmation that creating some type of facade was the way to go. I also was not sure why it wasn't done here so I thought I was missing something.  Spring would be ideal, and I hope to migrate it to that framework at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface for the service layer, internally all your code can work with that. Then make a class that uses that interface and calls the third party api methods and as the api facade.

i.e.

```
interface IAPIEndpoint {
    MyDomainDataEntity getData();
}

class MyAPIEndpoint : IAPIEndpoint {

    public MyDomainDataEntity getData() {
        MyDomainDataEntity dataEntity = new MyDomainDataEntity();
        // Call the third party api and fill it
        return dataEntity;
    }
}
```

It is always a good idea to interface out third party apis so you don't get their funk invading your app domain, and you can swap out as needed.  You could make another class implementation that uses a different service entirely.

To use it in code you just call

```
IAPIEndpoint endpoint = new MyAPIEndpoint(); // or get it specific to the lang you are using.
```

Making your stuff based on interfaces when it spans multiple implementations is the way to go.  It works great for TDD as well so you can just swap out the interface to a local test one that can inspect your domain code entirely separate from the third party api.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I think that makes sense.  Let me ask a question to make sure I understand: I can use this approach and create the interface - in one impl I can call the third party api, in another impl I can call a test impl of the api so I can test in isolation. Is that correct?  My concern is how I'm going to handle the methods in the API object when I have to call them (mostly set/get but there are some methods).

Comment: Yeh finding common ground is always tricky.  Yes the interface describes what you app will use consistently across all implementations (classes using the interface or impl in java world).  I tend to put only the common methods that are 'genericized' into the main interface.  Then any specific api methods that are used by these methods in an implementation can do specific methods for the implementation.  For instance here we have a matchup server and we call an interface for FindMatch(), StartMatch(), CloseMatch() etc.  Those are in the interface.  Then in a Gamecenter...

Comment: implementation of that class we use the GameCenter calls to get a match, start a match, close a match and have many other methods that those calls use specific to GameCenter as private methods.  Then we can easily swap with a Test implementation that locally runs and also another matchup server that is self-hosted.  So our three third party or unique uses are all commonized by the interface with generic calls.  HTH Interfaces are also very common in web service server/client setups where all the code might not be on the client and only the interface and container classes need to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction; implement a [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) which will provide the transition from internal to external and back.

Then if you switched vendors your internals would remain valuable and you could change out the vendor specific code; assuming the vendors provide the same functionality and the data types related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I will be the black sheep here and advocate for the [YAGNI](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) principle.  The problem is that if you do an abstraction layer now, it will look so close to the third party API that it will just be a redundant layer.  Since you don't know now what a hypothetical future second vendor's API will look like, you don't know what differences you need to account for, and any future port is likely to require a rework for those unforeseen differences anyway.

If you need a test framework, my recommendation is to make your own test implementation using the same API as the BPM vendor.  Even better, almost all reputable API providers provide some sort of sandbox mode for testing.  If they don't, you should ask for one.

Comment: Karl I agree to an extent. What ends up happening though is that unless a formal layer exists between the vendor and the application the vendors implementation via types and API behavior begins to surface further upstream then it should. Once you do switch vendors you begin to realize how coupled you were to the vendors implementation; whereas an abstraction layer forces you to think about your applications needs first; abstracting away the vendor types and API oddities.

Comment: I agree I typically don't do this unless I have an immediate need for two implementations or a web service where we try to limit the client side code.  But for testing and TDD style is is very helpful.  The cool thing about the abstraction is that you can have a ProductionThirdPartyAPI implementation, a test implementation, and a test DevelopmentThirdPartyAPI so you can swap out development and production api layers, that alone might be worth it.